# Creating own object detection for Euro pallets

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow, object-detection

I thought about tackling a new project in which I use Tensorflow object detection API to detect Euro pallets ([eg. pic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EUR-pallet)).

My ultimate goal is to know how far I am away from the pallet and which relative position I have to it. So I thought about first detecting the euro pallet in an RGB feed from a kinect camera and then using its 3D feature to get the distance to the pallet.

But how do I go about the relative position of the pallet? I could create different classes, for example one is "Front view laying pallet" another one `Side view laying pallet` etc. but I think for that to be accurate I'd need quite a few pictures for each class for it to be valid? Like 200 for each class?

Since my guess is that there are no such labeled datasets yet thats quite a pain to create by myself.

Another way I could think of, is if I label my pallets with segmentation instead of bounding boxes, maybe there is another way to find out my relative position to the pallet? I never did semantic segmentation labeling myself but can anyone name any good programs which I could use?

I'm hoping someone can help point me in the right direction. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas: assuming detection and segmentation with classifier(s) works, one could then try feature detection like edges / lines to obtain clues about its orientation (bounding box).

Of course this will be tricky for simple feature detection because of very different surfaces (wood, dirt), backgrounds and lighting.

Also, "markerless tracking" (a topic in augmented reality) and "bin picking" (actually applied in the automation industry) may be keywords for similar problems, although you are probably not starting with an unordered pile of pallets.